How to prevent Swagger UI from following 302 redirects and/or downloading binary files?
I have published a Swagger UI for my API, which lets consumers invoke it in an interactive and user-friendly fashion.
Some of the API endpoints return a HTTP 302 redirect with a presigned S3 URL in a Location header. This causes Swagger UI to follow the redirect and then spin indefinitely, as it cannot download the binary file (why?).
To mitigate this problem, I would like to either prevent Swagger UI from following the HTTP 302 redirect or prevent it from trying to the download binary files.
How can I achieve this? Is there any standard solution?
